# Using imageMSO icons in add-in commands

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I recently starteted with office web add-ins using JS. My first project is migrating an existing VSTO add-in (coded in C#) to the new framework. The VSTO add-in has a custom UI where I used icons provided by Microsoft, the so called imageMSO icons (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/fe2124a1-5aaa-4adf-b285-5d58da9d5e2a). It is very easy to use these icons in RibbonXML via the `imageMSO="..."` property:

```
<button id="AddIn.Button1" label="Button One" imageMso="TableStyleNew"
        screentip="This is Button1" onAction="Button1_Click"/>
```

However, I was not able to find any information abot how these icons can be used in Office web add-ins. Is it possible to use the imageMSO incons for Office web add-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to host and provide your own icons in Office.js add-ins. Read more on manifest's [Resources element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/resources) and acceptable images.

Comment: What a step backwards....